# Characterizing McDuff Factors in Terms of Central Sequences

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a II$_1$ factor von Neumann algebra with two-norm $\|\cdot\|_2$ induced by its canonical normal, faithful trace. It is said to be a *McDuff Factor* provided it tensorily absorbs the hyperfinite II$_1$ factor $R$; that is, $M \cong M \overline{\otimes} R$.

A sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \in \ell^{\infty}(\Bbb{N},M)$ is said to be *central* if $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\|xx_n - x_n x\|_2 = 0$$ for any $x \in M$.Two central sequences $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ and $(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ are said to be *equivalent* if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \|x_n - y_n\|_2 =0$$ Finally, a central sequence is said to be *trivial* if it is equivalent to a scalar sequence.

I've also seen that $M$ is a McDuff factor is equivalent to the existence of pairs of non-commuting non-trivial central sequences in $M$. But I don't know exactly what that means. Would someone help me parse this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Non-commuting central sequences* means that you have two central sequences $(x_n)$, $(y_n)$ such that $(x_ny_n-y_nx_n)$ is not equivalent to the zero sequence. The point of view here is that one fixes a free ultrafilter $\omega$ and considers the II$_1$-factor $M^\omega=\ell^\infty(\mathbb N,M)/J$, where $J$ is the ideal of sequences equivalent to zero. The trace is $\tau_\omega([(x_n)])=\lim_\omega\tau(x_n)$. The (classes of) central sequences form $M'\cap M^\omega$. So two non-commuting central sequences correspond to two elements in $M'\cap M^\omega$ that do not commute.

McDuff proved that a II$_1$-factor $M$ is isomorphic to $M\otimes R$, with $R$ the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor, if and only if $M'\cap M^\omega$ is non-commutative; equivalently, if and only if there exist non-commuting central sequences in $M$.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not correct. Two sequences are non-equivalent if they induce different elements in the ultrapower $M^\omega$, and non-commuting if they induce non-commuting elements in the ultrapower $M^\omega$. You always have non-equivalent central sequences, for example $(1)_n$ and $(0)_n$.

Comment: Good you noticed! I have re-written the answer, please take a look.

Comment: Looks good to me. There's a bit of a technical point that a sequence not equivalent to zero in the sense of the OP (with limit $n\to\infty$) can still be zero in the ultrapower for some fixed $\omega$, but will be non-zero in some ultrapower. But being McDuff is independent of the free ultrafilter, so one can always choose an appropriate $\omega$. But I never really studied the set-theoretic intricacies surrounding ultrapowers.

Comment: If $N$ is a  Mcduff factor and $N$  is the von Neumann algebra of $M$. Does $M$ have some special property?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the" von Neumann algebra. But no, for starters you have $N\subset B(H)$, the fact that $N$ is McDuff tells you absolutely nothing about $B(H)$, other than that $\dim H=\infty$.

Comment: The definition of "McDuff factors"  can be generalized to other types?  If we discuss the type III factor $M$, can we have the above conclusion: $M′∩M^{\omega}$ is non-commutative?

Comment: The definition ($M\simeq M\otimes R$) is certainly type-agnostic, but the theorems are likely not. And for starters you would have to decide what $M^\omega$ means when $M$ is type III, as you don't have a canonical state (the trace).